# Android TextView Spacing Inconsistency

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, spacing

I have four TextViews in a RelativeLayout set up horizontally side by side.  There are no margins in between the TextViews and they all have the same background.  Sometimes the TextViews appear like they have a one pixel space in between each other.  Other times they appear to be touching.

Does anyone know what may cause this inconsistency in the layout or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using TableLayout for consistent spacing between Textview...

Comment: I will try linearlayout and tablelayout and let you know if it works.